# cannot display console log result as well in browser html

Tags: html, node.js, console

I do nodejs modules which can generate receipt, for consolelog result is okay but when displayed cannot be as well in console log. 
I do in html view like this :

```
**$( document ).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:5556/printinvoice',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            $('#demo-container').html(data);
        }
    });
});**
```

but why the result cannot be same ? can someone help to solve this problem ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of object is your "demo-container"? Have you tried putting your receipt in a textarea?

```
<textarea id="demo-container" rows="60" cols="60" readonly="readonly"></textarea>
```

HTML processes your input entirely differently than the console log. First of all it deletes all excess whitespaces including spaces and line endings as you can see.

Comment: thanks it works, i forget should be displayed in texttarea, I used <div> before

Comment: hii Bence could you give me idea how to make same with console log result ? check link my attachment photos https://snag.gy/Fnb6kC.jpg

Comment: Sure, you can make it monospace. Put this in your CSS:
textarea {
    font-family: monospace
}

Answer (score 0):

Jquery `.html()` Specifies the new content for the selected elements (can contain HTML tags). The data which you get from API call is a string without any `HTML` tags. The browser renders HTML tags else it will treat content as a string. If there is a HTML tag as a part of string then Jquery `.html()` method format it as it displayed in console.log

For reference please take a look on the following link
[Jquery .html method](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_html.asp)